# "Diccionario al uso" versus "diccionario de uso"

Tags: diccionarios

Quisiera saber si "diccionario al uso y "diccionario de uso" (¿o quizás "diccionario del uso"?) significan lo mismo.

De [Los 5 mejores diccionarios online de español](https://onspainschool.com/es/top-5-diccionarios-en-espanol/):

> La Fundación del Español Urgente no es un diccionario al uso. Sin embargo, puede sernos de ayuda para solventar las dudas de “cómo se escribe tal cosa”, o si debemos traducir algunas palabras directamente al español o dejarlas como están".

No he podido encontrar "diccionario al uso" buscando en Google.

Answer (score 3):

Son cosas distintas.

***Diccionario de uso del español*** es el nombre del [diccionario elaborado por María Moliner](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diccionario_de_uso_del_espa%C3%B1ol). En él explica que:

> La denominación **"de uso"** aplicada a este diccionario significa que constituye un instrumento para guiar en el uso del español

Existen otros diccionarios llamados **"de uso"** que en general tienen la misma pretensión que el de María Moliner.

La expresión **"al uso"** la define el [DLE](https://dle.rae.es/uso#T1toCO7) como:

> 1. loc. adj. Usual y común en un tiempo. El cine comercial al uso.
> 2. loc. adv. Conforme a la costumbre. Elaborado al uso tradicional.

Puesto que la Fundéu no es lo que por lo general entendemos como un diccionario, no es un diccionario **"al uso"**. El ***Diccionario de uso del español*** tampoco es un diccionario **"al uso"**, ni en su organización ni en parte de su contenido, que no se encuentra en otros diccionarios ([un ejemplo](http://www.mariamoliner.com/verbos_4ter.pdf)).

Comment: Tienes razón. No puse enlaces por pereza. Intentaré acordarme de ponerlos en el futuro.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus detalladas explicaciones! 